# Keep existing UV rotation during unwrap

Tags: uv

is it possible to **preserve the existing UV rotation** I have when I unwrap a model again? A UV-unwrapped model needs to be scaled wider. This results in the UVs being stretched. Re-unwrapping the model fixes the stretching, however, I then have to **rotate all the UVs again** to be correctly aligned and that is quite tedious. Is there an add-on or a technique you know of that can stop the UVs from rotating during unwrap, or is there a better way to fix UV stretching without having to re-unwrap? Thanks so much!!

-Adam